# Magento 2 : place order after a click on place order button in custom payment module

Tags: magento2, module, custom, payment, place-order

I'm a beginner on Magento. I try to create a `custom payment module`. All work fine but when I click on the "place order" button on the checkout page, the order is not add to the orders list of the current user.

I want to make `custom action` after a click on the "place order" button before calling if it exists, the default action set by Magento to add an order to the orders list of the current user using the current quote.

**Something like that:**

```
placeOrder: function() {
   //When the user click on "place order" button
   
   //Custom module action
   //action_1
   //action_2
       .
       .
       .
   //action_n

   //Call the default magento action to create an order using the current quote
   magento_default_placeOrder_action();
}
```

Comment: You can use below like to generate simple payment module
https://mage2gen.com/
https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module

Comment: Hi Nayem! Thank you for you help! I apologize for answering after so much time. I was testing the solution you recommended, adapting it to my needs. Everything works properly now. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's ok. Glad it's helped.